# Connection refused: connect - Java mail API

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am getting the below error while sending email from corporate outlook using java mail API.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:       smtp.mycompany.net.au, port: 25;
 nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

I am able to telnet the server with the same port my machine.What could be the root cause of the issue?

Code used for sending email is  -

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", mysmtpserver);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", myport);

Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
            });

Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress));

message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC, addressTo);
message.setSubject(emailSubject);

BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable"); 
messageBodyPart.setContent(emailBody, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();  
//part 1-add html part
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
String filename = reportFilePath.trim();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));                    
messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);                  
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
```

Appreciated any help in resolving it.

Thanks
Libin

Comment: That means your port is open but it refuses the connection

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using telnet on the same machine that your JavaMail application is running on, and you're connecting to port 25 on smtp.mycompany.net.au, right?  Do you get the SMTP greeting message from the server?

Comment: Can you show us code to understand well where are you making mistake. Perhaps you are not setting properties accurately

Comment: I am using the below properties in my code -Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.mycompany.net.au");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

Comment: I was able to send messages using gmail smpt server using the same code.Issue started coming after i started using corporate smtp server.

Comment: I have added the code in the question for review.

Comment: Sona I have updated my answer. Please feel free to let me know if you have any further problem.

Answer (score 0):

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect error throws due to the following reasons that you have to check:

1. Your hostname or port
2. Your properties code is accurately written
3. Make sure firewall is not blocking the port
4. Provide password if your server require it

Thanks for providing your code. Pleas apply the following code. Its very easy understandable and works fine. 100% tested

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;   
import javax.mail.event.*;      
import java.net.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail extends ConfigProperties{

        public static void send(String from, String to, String subject, String content) throws AddressException, MessagingException{

        ErrorCheck ec   = new ErrorCheck();
        String error = "";

        try{
            error   = ec.error();

            String smtp = getPropVal("SMTP");
            String host = getPropVal("HOST");

            Properties props=new Properties();
                props.put(smtp,host);
            Session   session1  =  Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
            Message msg =new MimeMessage(session1);

            msg.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            msg.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "quoted-printable");           

               msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                   msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(to,false));
               msg.setSubject(subject);
               msg.setContent(content,"text/html; charset=UTF-8");      

                Transport.send(msg); 

            }catch(Exception e){
            ec.errorMsg(error+"SendEmail.send()", e);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How can we check if a firewall is blocking port? @Ghayel